# Performing Find+Replace on a specific region and for letters that can be part of any word

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a contact manager project in Eclipse that contains addresses and phoneNumbers.
The methods for adding one (in this case to a tree node) is nearly identical to the other except that the variables and methods say Phone instead of Address. For instance getPhoneIterator() becomes getAddressIterator().
I'm looking for a way to just highlight the whole paragraph and change everywhere the letters "ADDRESS" appear together, to the letters "PHONE".

Is there a way to do that?

For illustration, here is my code;

```
// Checking if there are addresses, and 
// then checking and adding them one by one to the tree.
if (!currentContact.addressCollectionIsEmpty()){ //If there are addresses...
    addressMainNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Addresses");
    Iterator<Address> addressItr = currentContact.getAddressIterator();
    while(addressItr.hasNext()){
        Address currentAddress = addressItr.next();
        addressSpecificNode = 
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode(currentAddress.toString());
        addressMainNode.add(addressSpecificNode);
    }
    contactNode.add(addressMainNode);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that indicate the need to modularize that block into a generic method and call with appropriate parameters?

Comment: I think I know what you're saying... can you elaborate more? Aren't things a little too specific here for a generic method? I mean, how would I perform getAddressIterator() in a generic method?

Comment: Please see the response below on how this snippet can be moved to a generic method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!currentContact.addressCollectionIsEmpty())
{
    addressMainNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Addresses");
    Iterator<Address> addressItr = currentContact.getAddressIterator();
    while(addressItr.hasNext()){
        Address currentAddress = addressItr.next();
        addressSpecificNode = 
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode(currentAddress.toString());
        addressMainNode.add(addressSpecificNode);
    }
    contactNode.add(addressMainNode);
}
```

The above portion of code could be moved into a generic method as follows:

```
public <T> addToContactNode(
    boolean isEmpty,
    String treeNodeName,
    Iterator<T> itr) 
{
    if (isEmpty) {
        return;
    }
    mainNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(treeNodeName);
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        T current = itr.next();
        specificNode = 
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode(current.toString());
        mainNode.add(addressSpecificNode);
    }
    contactNode.add(mainNode);
}
```

And the above method will be called as follows:

```
// Add addresses.
addToContactNode(
    currentContact.addressCollectionIsEmpty(),
    "Addresses",
    currentContact.getAddressIterator());

// Add Phones.
addToContactNode(
    currentContact.phoneCollectionIsEmpty(),
    "Phones",
    currentContact.getPhoneIterator());
```

Comment: Do I have to make class generic too? i.e. How does the method know what to make of `<T>`? What will it return?

Comment: Do I need to call it with `<Address>addToContactNode(
    currentContact.addressCollectionIsEmpty(),
    "Addresses",
    currentContact.getAddressIterator());`

Comment: The type can be obtained from the Iterator. Otherwise, you can call it as `this.<Address>addToContactNode(...)` to explicitly specify the type.